# Youtube api playlist number of videos

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, youtube, playlist

I'm using this script: https://github.com/badsyntax/jquery-youtube-player

I get only the 24 first video's from the playlist. The [YT api manual](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_playlists) says it can be up to 200 video's. Is there something wrong with the script, or does the api only give 24 video's back?

---

Online example: http://badsyntax.github.com/jquery-youtube-player/examples/player-multiple-playlists.html

Comment: Put an example online (preferably a jsFiddle) to demonstrate what goes wrong.

Comment: I want to bump this question because it´s a important one for me. Does anyone know how much video´s the YT api give´s back normally?